# How does Wikipedia make its search field?

Tags: search, wikipedia, searchbar

I would like to know how Wikipedia does its search field.  What I mean by this is two things:  Its gradient and its button.

How does it make a gradient in the field?  This can be easily done with CSS cross browser at this point, but when you do the IE CSS code, it aliases the text.  Wikipedia has a gradient background, but the text is still anti-aliased!  How do they do that?

Also, how did they put a clickable search button INSIDE the text field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the actual search input has no styling -- meaning no border and a transparent background.  The containing div is styled to look like an input field (border and gradient).  The clickable button is inside the div but not inside the actual input element.

Comment: It took awhile to figure out what exactly they were doing. I'm still stuck in the mindset that transparent colors are something that belongs in the far-off future where all browsers can play nice together

Answer (score 0):

You could just look at the code. The search box as it appears is only a div element with a border. This div itself has the gradient set via CSS (background-image). As you can see the button element is also not inside the text field.

```
<div id="simpleSearch">
    <input id="searchInput" name="search" type="text"  title="Search Wikipedia [f]" accesskey="f"  value="" />
    <button id="searchButton" type='submit' name='button'  title=""><img src="[x]" alt="Filltext" /></button>
</div>
```